# How to limit count of SMS sent by SMPPsim

Tags: sms, smpp

I'm using SMPPsim to sent SMS to my task through it's MO Service.
I've put 15000 messages into deliver_messages.csv file, but SMPPsim sends them permanently.
Is there any way to limit count of SMS sent by SMPPsim?

Answer (score 0):

As per SMPPSim there is no logic implemented to limit the count of messages.

For more details you can find classes called MoService.java ,MoMessagePool.java in SMPPSim source code .Smppsim simply fetching the values  DELIVER_MESSAGES_FILE ,DELIVERY_MESSAGES_PER_MINUTE from smppsim.props and submitting respectively .